# choosing the right date format for data in json

Tags: elasticsearch, localdate

I am working with elastic search i want to create a search by range of dates i am thinking of using LocalDate for this only problem is my date in the json data  looks like this

```
 {
        "departure": {
            "city": "\u041c\u0438\u043d\u0441\u043a",
            "date": "Aug 27, 2018 12:09:00 AM"
        },
```

I have a about 1000 of such so its not wise for me to change each date in json to yyyy-mm-dd format

my search method is in java as such.

```
 public List<Map<String, Object>> searchDao(LocalDate departureDateFrom, LocalDate departureDateTo,
                                               String countryOrCityOrHotel, int nights, int people, String departureCity) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> search = new ArrayList<>();


        QueryBuilder range = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("date")
                 .from(departureDateFrom)
                 .to(departureDateTo)
                .includeLower(true)
                .includeUpper(true);

        QueryBuilder cityQuery = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("departure.city", departureCity);
        QueryBuilder nightsQuery = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("nights", nights);
        QueryBuilder peopleQuery = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("people", people);
        QueryBuilder destinationHotel = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("hotel.country", countryOrCityOrHotel);
```

How do i change my local date format to accepts such dates so its easier to work with data as they are.

Comment: I don't think that your `departure.date` field was recognized as a date field when you indexed the document. You probably need to change your mapping as well. Feel free to share it. Then you can use [whatever date format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#_date_format_in_range_queries) you wish in your `range` query, but the date field **must** be a date in your mapping first.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a the right mapping in your index template:
 {
    "departure.date": {
          "type": "date" 
     }
}

And in your java code to write this:

```
QueryBuilder range = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("date")
             .from(departureDateFrom)
             .to(departureDateTo)
             .format("MM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss")
             .includeLower(true)
             .includeUpper(true);
```

But in general its always a good idea to use epoch time when storing dates as strings are very fragile and formats tend to change all the time.

Comment: `yyyy-mm-dd` agrees with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). I don’t think it’s likely to change any time soon.